# Any way to access to a variable of type "var", defined in code behind, from aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, var

Linq queries stored in variables of type var. I would like to have foreach loops in aspx file for the queries. 
Default.aspx.cs:

```
var query = from ko in entity.Organizations select ko;
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%= foreach(var item in query)
{
    <li> item.name </li>
}%>
```

Normally, if we define a variable public inside the Page class (outside the Page_Load() method) we can access them within aspx. But var type cannot be defined as class members.

OK.
Now the problem is how to put "entity.Organization" where the "?" is. Having compile time error. (Context is from Entity Framework).

```
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {

    public Context entity = new Context();
    public IQueryable<?> query;
    ..
 }
```

Comment: `var` is not a type. LINQ queries have a definite type, usually `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`, which you can absolutely define as class member.

Comment: `var` isn't a type. It just tells the compiler "figure out what type this is for me."

Comment: I wouldn't do it like that, but hey, if you want it public than just explicitly define it as `public IQueryable<Organization> query`.

Comment: `var` could be a type if you declare it as `class var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework DbContext is having a collection of your entities not the entity class itself, so to use it IQueryable this will work.

For your example:

```
public IQueryable<Organization> query;
```